# Element not allowed: node@http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope

Tags: soap, soapui, xsd-validation

I am getting the following error, when I add a SOAP UI schema validation for as part of the assertions in SOAP UI:

```
Element not allowed: node@http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope in element Header@http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope
```

Can anyone please give me a clue why this is failing? And how to fix that?

XML validated:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:ns0="urn:xeu:flux-transport:v1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
<soap:node datetime="2018-02-02T10:31:08.006Z">ABC</soap:processingNode>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<blah>
</blah>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

WSDL (used to validate in SOAP UI):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <wsdl:documentation>Version: 1.0</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema>    
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   
        schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the element `node` or below line from your request:

```
<soap:node datetime="2018-02-02T10:31:08.006Z">ABC</soap:processingNode>
```

Also, start and end node names are different too.

Comment: Sorry - what I meant is how can I fix the validation and not the XML to validate it correctly?

Comment: I believe that node is not allowed there. Hence requested to remove the same.

Comment: I do understand - but how can I fix the schema so this can be validated?